# BIC in practice with gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mse, bic, likelihood

I am considering a Gaussian distribution:

\begin{equation}
y \sim N(\text{net}(x,w), \sigma^2).
\end{equation}

where $\text{net}()$ is just the output of some neural net with weights $w$ and input $x$.  The log-likelihood is

\begin{equation}
\log L = -\frac{n}{2} (\log(2\pi) + \log(\sigma^2)) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_i (y_i - \text{net}(x_i,w_i))^2
\end{equation}

and the BIC is

\begin{align}
BIC &= -2 \log L + \log(n) \cdot d \\[12pt]
&= n(\log(2\pi) + \log(\sigma^2)) + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_i (y_i - \text{net}(x_i,\hat{w}_i))^2 + \log(n) \cdot d \\[6pt]
&\approx \frac{n}{\sigma^2} \bigg( \text{MSE} + \frac{\log(n)\cdot d \cdot \sigma^2}{n} \bigg),
\end{align}

where $d$ is the number of parameters. What I wonder is, how do I estimate $\sigma^2$ in practice? My intuition was to estimate it with usual MLE which is the MSE, i.e.

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (y_i - \text{net}(x_i, \hat{w}_i))^2$$

but then the first term would just cancel out...
And does the variance count as a parameter in $d$? I am really confused how to use this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particular reason for not estimating $\sigma$ as in any Gaussian process, with sample standard deviation given a sample of outputs from the neural network for some fixed $x, \omega$

But make sure $\sigma$ is indeed independent from those!

And yes, $\sigma$ is a parameter in its own right!

Comment: Thank you! If I am getting you right, this is exactly the formula to estimate $\sigma^2$ that I have written down (which is the MSE). So you say that is okay that the is $BIC = n + \log(n) \cdot d$? That seems weird to me